# Dark mode with Paris

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm trying to implement dark mode in my application. As far as I know, the best solution is to use Paris library. Is there any simple solution to set dark mode globally in the application?
I found issue on the Paris github: https://github.com/airbnb/paris/issues/15 but it is not implemented. Any idea is there another way to set style once and not using `view.style(R.style.night_style)` on each view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different themes like below example :

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"></style>
```

Alternatively, if you want to define separate Light and Dark themes for your app, you can inherit from `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` in the values directory, and `Theme.MaterialComponents` in the values-night directory. E.g.:

**res/values/themes.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

**res/values-night/themes.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

> The Theme.MaterialComponents theme is a static dark theme, whereas
>   Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight is a more dynamic theme which will
>   help facilitate easy switching between your app’s Light and Dark
>   theme. If using a DayNight theme, you can define one app theme that
>   references color resources, which can be overridden in the
>   values-night directory if needed.

[Reference](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark/)